# Updating features in SDE database from Python without using ArcEditor License

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, basic-license-level

I have a non spatial data set that I would like to keep sync'ed in SDE as a spatial set. So I would like to be able to insert, update, and delete without using one of my two ArcEditor licenses since this will be running on a server.

Can I do this?

Clarification: I meant data set in the most general term, just a raw table in a DBMS that holds spatial data, but is not a part of any ESRI product.

Full explanation: We use a very old MapObjects customization that was purchased from a 3rd party vendor. It stores binary shape information (conforming to ESRI shapefile standards) in a binary column in MSSQL server. Every time an edit is made to a record in that datbase a trigger records the edit. As of now, there is an application that runs on a server that checks out an ESRI ArcEditor license and processes the edits (with ArcObjects) that have been made and makes the appropriate change in an SDE database with feature datasets and feature collections. I would like to avoid this use of a license on an unattended server for what would seem to me to be a normal use of SDE and not something inherent that requires an ArcEditor instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. I do this to load CSV files of control points from surveyors in multiple offices into SDE. Surveyors save their GPS files to a directory on the server, and nightly a python script runs to update the control layer in SDE.